# Class AB amplifier design using op-amp

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, audio

I'm currently working on an audio amplifier (first-time). To facilitate the negative feedback I decided using an Opamp to keep the circuit simple. I ended up with a simple emitter follower and a Vbe-multiplier for temperature compensation (currently adjusted for 50 mA quiescent current).

Is there anything obvious to improve or some bug I overlooked  (I’m not nailed down to the exact elements, I just used some models that would make sense for the initial simulation)?
[image: amplifier circuit]

Comment: How are you going to implement the current sources?

Comment: The problem with using an opamp for the input stage is that you need a high voltage one and it ends up costing more than the rest of the circuit, or you can use a lower voltage opamp and bootstrap it, which adds complexity.

The tried and true method is to use a differential pair followed by a voltage amplifier (VAS). High voltage transistors are cheap and plentiful and there are a lot of designs available to use as examples.
I would suggest looking at some of those designs and see if they wouldn't work better for you.

Comment: Mike, I don't think the current sources are a big concern, in LTSpice I've found that there's usually no noticeable difference between using the current source component vs. one done with transistors. I usually start with a current source to make it easy to set the current exactly, then when I've got everything working replace them with discrete components. I do the same with the Vbe multiplier, using a voltage source.

Comment: This is early-stage circuit design - it tends toward being more complex as you add tweaks. Besides correcting the VBE-compensator (they're unforgiving), don't forget a pull-to-gnd resistor on the op-amp "+" input, especially for a direct-coupled output like this. Add a fuse to the output, just in case something goes amuck.

Comment: What is the purpose of I2?

Comment: Ferio, Are you trying to make a \$\frac12\cdot\frac{\left(40\:\text{V}\right)^2}{4\:\Omega}=200\:\text{W}\$ amplifier?? That's some serious business!

Comment: Ferio, If you interact here (for example, answer @AnalogKid 's question about \$I_2\$) then I may consider spending a little time. If you say nothing at all, I'll also just bide my time.

Comment: @AnalogKid good question. I could swear it didn’t work without it. Considering jp314’s remark and looking at the circuit again it probably just acts as a load dump, so I should see a better performance since the opamp is stressed less. Currently I don’t see any improvement in the output signal though. I guess because my bias is way to high as mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: @jonk yes but more in the way of Stereo 2*100W@8Ohm. I’m just simulating with the smaller impedance to see if it still behaves. I didn’t calculate it yet but I guess I need to add at least another power transistor in parallel to do even that. But to be honest, at the end I’m probably limited by the transformer I can fit into a nice case anyway…

Comment: @Ferio I'd be willing to consider something. But there are so many more details to get right when dealing with this much power. I'm not sure how much I'm up for. Perhaps if I did something low power, but using a topology that is closer to what you'll need? Would that be okay?

Comment: @jonk I don’t know exactly what you are pointing at, but part of the exercise was doing the thing myself otherwise I could just got to ebay and buy a pcb :)

Comment: @Ferio I am thinking about a topology that would be appropriate for approximately the power you are considering (multiple BJTs per quadrant and an appropriate vbe multiplier with Early effect compensation that could be thermally coupled) but where I don't need to discuss dissipation or device temperature concerns, at length. That kind of thing is better handled by books. But I'm also not sure exactly what you want from someone here, either. So this uncertainty goes both ways, I suppose. Would you prefer good book recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

The Vbe multiplier is producing a bias voltage of about 4.5 V between the bases of Q1 and Q2 which I suspect is too high a voltage, although I don't actually know what the Vbe drops of Q1,Q2,Q3 & Q4 are.

A usual way of doing it would be to have a 1k multi-turn pot and a series limiting resistor instead of R8 and then, when setting up the amp, adjust the pot to get the required voltage across R5 & R9 and the required current through them once the amp has warmed up.

The pot and series limiting resistor should go between the base and emitter of Q5  instead of placing the pot in series with R7 because then if the pot wiper goes open circuit the bias voltage between the bases of Q1 & Q2 reduces instead of increasing.

Answer (score 3):

Q3-4 need base resistors or ferrite beads to prevent local oscillations (and solid decoupling of the power rails).

R8 should be a pot to adjust the bias. It is very important that R7 be a fixed resistor, so when the pot wiper fails open eventually, the amp will default to lowest bias. If R7 and R8 are the two sides of the pot, when the wiper fails open, you will get unlimited bias current and the output transistors will burn.

Given the max output voltage of this opamp is 1.5V from the positive rail, on positive clipping it will try to push Q1's base above the rail. This will reverse bias the top current source and fully saturate Q1. So you could put one diode in the opamp's power supply to drop its maximum output voltage slightly.

This output stage will have a double pole around a few MHz. Its frequency depends on output current and voltage. This adds phase lag and could make the whole feedback loop unstable, especially if the load is a bit capacitive like a loudspeaker cable. You could add a compensation cap or TMC network between the output of the opamp and its negative output.

I'm not sure one pair of 1302/3281 will do 40V into 4 ohms without exceeding SOA.

Comment: Thanks this (saturation of Q1) is something I didn’t think of at all. But it’s obvious since I’m biasing the power stage…

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need I2 -- the opamp will be able to sink the 6 mA from I1, although there is no harm in 'helping' it.

You have no output current limit -- if there is a short circuit or overload, you will likely damage the output devices (at least).

If this is a very high power circuit, you do need to thermally couple Q5 to the outputs Q3 and Q4. If you can't couple to both, you can duplicate Q5 (e.g. 2 in *parallel*), and mount one near Q3, one near Q5. That way the hottest one will define the bias point.

Comment: You are right it works without I2 and doesn’t change anything to the output. I’m planning to add some kind of speaker protection (relay) behind the output stage such that speakers don’t see any DC if something breaks.